# Fatal error: Uncaught DocuSign\eSign\Client\ApiException: Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code [302]

Tags: php, docusignapi

I created a demo app using the DocuSign Quickstart tool, but I get this error the moment my app attempts to use the "createEnvelope" function:

**$results = $envelopeApi->createEnvelope($GLOBALS['DS_CONFIG']['ds_client_id'], $envelope_definition);**

I'm sure it has to do with the Integration Key, but I don't know docusugn well enough to resolve the issue.
Any direction would be much appreciated.

Here's the full error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught DocuSign\eSign\Client\ApiException: Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code [302] with response Body: in C:\xampp\htdocs\embedded\vendor\docusign\esign-client\src\Client\ApiClient.php:344 Stack trace:
 #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\embedded\vendor\docusign\esign-client\src\Api\EnvelopesApi.php(4117): DocuSign\eSign\Client\ApiClient->callApi('/v2.1/accounts/...', 'POST', Array, '{"documents":[{...', Array, '\\DocuSign\\eSign...', '/v2.1/accounts/...')
 #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\embedded\vendor\docusign\esign-client\src\Api\EnvelopesApi.php(4023): DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi->createEnvelopeWithHttpInfo('xxxxxxxx-xxxx-x...', Object(DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeDefinition), NULL) 
 #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\embedded\public\index.php(117): DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi->createEnvelope('xxxxxxxx-xxxx-x...', Object(DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeDefinition)) 
 #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\embedded\public\index.php(169): Example\make_envelope(Array) #4 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\embedded\vendor\docusign\esign-client\src\Client\ApiClient.php on line 344
```

Comment: that's a 302 http status code which is a redirect. I think the API may be rerouting you to a login page or possibly a consent authorization page if you're using a new key. Try to manually navigate to the page for the very first time to grant consent for the API.

Answer (score 3):

From the error trace, specifically the path "C:\xampp\htdocs\embedded\vendor\docusign\esign-client\src\Client\ApiClient.php", it looks like you deleted the outer folder.

I'm curious to know what you put in your C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf file. This setting in the httpd.conf file needs to match if you've deleted that folder:
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/Tally_Customer_Portal-php"

Answer (score 2):

I would go through the [quickstart guide](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/) on DocuSign. That way it will build out the code you need to get started. I would also make sure your token information is correct as well.

Answer (score 0):

I lifted this code from a few different sources, and unfortunately it came with a few different problems. The one in this particular case was from the 'ds_client_id' value, which the QuickStart guide automatically assigns with your Integration Key. When running the createEnvelope function, you need your Account ID, not the Integration Key.